# How to install python package namespace from private bitbucket-git repository

Tags: python, pip, package, bitbucket

I have several related projects that I think will be a good fit for Python's [namespace-packages](https://packaging.python.org/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/). I'm currently running python 3.8, and have created the following directory structure for testing.

```
├── namespace-package-test.package1
│   ├── LICENSE.txt
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── setup.cfg
│   ├── setup.py
│   ├── src
│   │   └── pkg1
│   │       ├── cli
│   │       │   ├── __init__.py
│   │       │   └── pkg1_cli.py
│   │       └── __init__.py
│   └── tests
├── namespace-package-test.package2
│   ├── AUTHORS.rst
│   ├── CHANGELOG.rst
│   ├── LICENSE.txt
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── setup.cfg
│   ├── setup.py
│   ├── src
│   │   └── pkg2
│   │       ├── cli
│   │       │   ├── __init__.py
│   │       │   └── pkg2_cli.py
│   │       └── __init__.py
│   └── tests
```

The entire project is on a private bitbucket (cloud) server at;

```
git@bitbucket.org:<my-company>/namespace-package-test.git
```

I would like to install, locally, only package 1. I've tried every iteration I can imagine of the following, but nothing seems to get me there. I either get a repository not found error or a setup.py not found error.

```
pip install git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org:<my-company>/namespace-package-test.package1.git
```

1. Is this possible?
2. Is my project structure correct for what I am doing?
3. What should the pip install command look like?
4. Bonus, what if I only want to install a specific spec using pipx?

```
pipx install "namespace-package-test.package1[cli] @ git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org:<my-company>/namespace-package-test.package1.git"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured it out ... for posterity sake

**Pip install (into virtual environment)**

```
pip install git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/<company name>/namespace-package-test.git/#subdirectory=namespace-package-test.package1
```

**pipx install - with spec**

```
pipx install "namespace-package-test.package1[cli] @ git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/<company name>/namespace-package-test.git/#subdirectory=namespace-package-test.package1"
```