# Python package-namespace: common test/docs/setup.py or one per namespace - which is the better pattern?

Tags: python, package

(In the interest of transparency, this is a follow up to a question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64564188/how-to-install-python-package-namespace-from-private-bitbucket-git-repository/64565952#64565952))

I'm dealing with related files in which a namespace package seems a good fit. I'm following the guide from the [packaging authority](https://packaging.python.org/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/), which places a setup.py in each namespace package;

```
mynamespace-subpackage-a/
    setup.py
    mynamespace/
        subpackage_a/
            __init__.py

mynamespace-subpackage-b/
    setup.py
    mynamespace/
        subpackage_b/
            __init__.py
        module_b.py
```

In my tests, created a similar project. Apart from setup.py, I placed my unit tests, docs, and other stuff per namespace (I left out some of the directories for compactness.). I used pyscaffold to generate the namespaces.

```
├── namespace-package-test.package1
│   ├── LICENSE.txt
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── setup.cfg
│   ├── setup.py
│   ├── src
│   │   └── pkg1
│   │       ├── cli
│   │       │   ├── __init__.py
│   │       │   └── pkg1_cli.py
│   │       └── __init__.py
│   └── tests
├── namespace-package-test.package2
│   ├── AUTHORS.rst
```

However, I then noticed that pyscaffold has the option to create namespaces packages in the putup command.

```
(venv) steve@PRVL10SJACKSON:~/Temp$ putup --force my-package -p pkg1 --namespace namespace1
(venv) steve@PRVL10SJACKSON:~/Temp$ putup --force my-package -p pkg1 --namespace namespace2
```

This creates a folder structure like this;

```
├── AUTHORS.rst
├── CHANGELOG.rst
├── LICENSE.txt
├── README.rst
├── requirements.txt
├── setup.cfg
├── setup.py
├── src
│   ├── namespace1
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── pkg1
│   │       ├── __init__.py
│   │       └── skeleton.py
│   └── namespace2
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── pkg1
│           ├── __init__.py
│           └── skeleton.py
└── tests
    ├── conftest.py
    └── test_skeleton.py
```

So I'm conflicted; I trust the team at pyscaffold, but it goes against the example from the packaging authority.

1. **Are both approaches valid?**
2. **Is there a reason to choose one approach over the other?**

Answer (score 1):

The idea behind the namespace option in PyScaffold is to share/reuse namespaces across projects (in opposite of having more than one namespace inside a single project). Or in other words, to split a larger project in independently maintained/developed projects.

To my best understanding, having an structure like the one you showed in the 4th code block will not work. Using `putup --force` twice with 2 different namespaces for the same root folder is not the intended/supported usage.

The approach of PyScaffold is the same as the package authority, the only difference is that PyScaffold will assume you have only one package contained in a single project and git repository (PyScaffold also uses a `src` directory for the reasons explained in [Ionel's blog post](https://blog.ionelmc.ro/2014/05/25/python-packaging/#the-structure))

The reason behind adopting one `setup.py` per namespace+package is that it is required for building separated distribution files (i.e. you need one `setup.py` per `*.whl`).